# Hide UI Angular Tabs

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-tabset

I am trying to implement UI Bootstrap tabs, plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/12G8WLrpMjPdzfNmxh9b?p=preview), i want to hide the tabs as i will be using the button  to change the tabs.

i am adding this class to my CSS file but it is not applied to the tabs

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: none;
}
```

my end goal is to hide [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBLRZ.png). How do i approach for it?

Comment: Can you use Jquery ?

Comment: yes i can use it.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2637, its an issue with Angulr

Comment: that was for tab contents. 
I wanted to hide the tab headings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you just add an ng-hide="true"?

```
 <uib-tab index="$index" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-hide="true" heading="{{tab.title}}" disable="tab.disabled">
  {{tab.content}}
</uib-tab>
```

Comment: also, you can bind to a variable instead of using true or false

Comment: So one problem was the tab heading baseline was still visible, 
any idea how to hide that ?

Comment: @Pujan it looks like that's a style that you'll have to override if you want to get rid of it

Comment: .nav > li > a, .nav-tabs {

  display: none;
}



this solved it :)  thanks